# Change values of variables in class swift

Tags: class, cocoa, swift, class-variables, xcode-6.2

I have 2 classed: `Game` and `ViewController` (subclass of `NSViewController`) that's `Game` class:

```
class Game {

required init(num : CGFloat, picName : String, gameName : String, description : String, windowHeight : CGFloat) {
    self.number = num
    self.pictureName = picName
    self.name = gameName
    self.desc = description
    self.height = windowHeight
}

var number : CGFloat
var pictureName : String
var name : String
var desc : String
var height : CGFloat

var image : NSImage {
    return NSImage(named: pictureName)!
}

var imageView : NSImageView {
    return NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 100, width: 100, height: 100))
}

var nameField : NSTextField {
    return NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 100, width: 300, height: 30))
}

var descField : NSTextField {
    return NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 140, width: 300, height: 60))
}


func setImage() {
    imageView.image = image
}

func setNameField() {
    nameField.font = NSFont(name: "System", size: 15.0)
    nameField.stringValue = "Name"
    nameField.alignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 2)!
    nameField.selectable = false
    nameField.editable = false
}

func setDescField() {
    descField.selectable = false
    descField.editable = false
    descField.stringValue = desc
    descField.font = NSFont(name: "System", size: 11.0)
}

}
```

And in `viewDidAppear` I do this:

```
var size = self.view.window?.frame.size
    var newGame = Game(num: 1, picName: "Bomb.png", gameName: "Bomber", description: "Just a simpla application", windowHeight: size!.height)
    newGame.setDescField()
    newGame.setImage()
    newGame.setNameField()
    println(newGame.descField.editable)
    self.view.addSubview(newGame.imageView)
    self.view.addSubview(newGame.descField)
    self.view.addSubview(newGame.nameField)
```

And `descField.editable` is always `true`, even though I write `descField.editable = false` in function in class `Game`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to declare all fields and image view as lazy variables and work with them in `init`:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import AppKit

class Game {

init(num : CGFloat, picName : String, gameName : String, description : String, windowHeight : CGFloat, sender : NSViewController) {
    self.number = num
    self.pictureName = picName
    self.name = gameName
    self.desc = description
    self.height = windowHeight
    imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    nameField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: 60, width: 300, height: 30))
    descField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: 0, width: 300, height: 60))

    nameField.font = NSFont(name: "System", size: 15.0)
    nameField.stringValue = self.name
    nameField.alignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: 2)!
    nameField.selectable = false
    nameField.editable = false
    nameField.backgroundColor = sender.view.window?.backgroundColor
    nameField.bordered = false

    descField.selectable = false
    descField.editable = false
    descField.stringValue = desc
    descField.font = NSFont(name: "System", size: 11.0)
    descField.backgroundColor = NSColor.controlColor()
    descField.bordered = true
    descField.backgroundColor = sender.view.window?.backgroundColor

    imageView.image = NSImage(named: self.pictureName)!

    gameView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: /*height - (100 * num)*/ height - (120 * num), width: 600, height: 100))

    button = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 100))
    button.tag = Int(number)
    button.action = nil

    var gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: sender, action: Selector("buttonPressed:"))
    gesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
    gesture.buttonMask = 0x1
    button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    button.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle(rawValue: 6)!
    button.transparent = true

    gameView.addSubview(nameField)
    gameView.addSubview(imageView)
    gameView.addSubview(descField)
    gameView.addSubview(button)

}

var number : CGFloat
var pictureName : String
var name : String
var desc : String
var height : CGFloat

lazy var button : NSButton = NSButton()
lazy var imageView : NSImageView = NSImageView()
lazy var nameField : NSTextField = NSTextField()
lazy var descField : NSTextField = NSTextField()
lazy var gameView : NSView = NSView()

}
```

And then you call this all like that:

```
var newGame = Game(num: number, picName: "Bomb2.png", gameName: "Bomber", description: "Just a simple application", windowHeight: size!.height, sender: self)
self.view.addSubview(newGame.gameView)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written, you're generating a new instance of NSTextField every time you access nameField, and so on.

You want to use lazy instantiation, which is easily supported by the adding the 'lazy' keyword:

```
lazy var nameField : NSTextField {
     return NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 100, width: 300, height: 30))
 }
```

or even more simply:

```
lazy var nameField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 100, width: 300, height: 30))
```

Do the same for image, imageView, and descField.

Comment: I've written `lazy var nameField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 100, width: 300, height: 30))` and haven't changed anything else, and now it shows an error `Game.Type does not have a member named 'height'`

Comment: and also it writes that lazy var can not be a computed property

Comment: height was from your code... I'm not sure where your'e getting that but I assumed you knew.

Comment: I found that strange too. That error appears only when `nameField` and others are computed properties, otherwise it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

How about like that:

```
var descField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 110, y: height - (110 * (number - 1)) - 140, width: 300, height: 60))
var editable: Bool {
    get {
        return descField.editable
    }
    set {
        descField.editable = newValue
    }
}
```

And the you can use your game instance:

```
var newGame //......
newGame.editable = true
```

Comment: The same error as below... `Game.Type does not have a member named 'height'`

Comment: Sorry, I was copying my answer wrong, I tested in my Xcode that code with this "var descField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 25))"